# Fundamental group of Calabi-Yau 3-fold in string theory

Tags: string-theory, compactification, calabi-yau

In string theory, we compactify a 10-dimensional space by a Calabi-Yau 3-fold to reduce the dimension to 4. To get a reasonable theory, a Calabi-Yau 3-fold should satisfy some properties. One is the Euler number must be $\pm6$ so that it is compatible with the generation of the elementary particles.

I heard that the fundamental group of the Calabi-Yau 3-fold should not be trivial. What should it be?

Comment: Not my field, but do you mean the Euler characteristic (number's a bit vague - for someone outside the field it reads like "well, Euler Characteristic is most likely meant, but since it's not my field I'm not sure).

Comment: If I follow the page $1$ of this [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0212221), it is because gauge instantons/Wilson Lines on Calabi-Yau with trivial fundamental group, can only break $E_8$ symmetry to $E_6, SO(10), SU(5)$ GUT groups, but not to more interesting phenomenologically groups like $SU(3)*SU(2)*U(1)$

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimal aka Rod Vance In mathematics, "Euler number" and "Euler characteristic" are the same. Since there is also "holomorphic Euler characteristic", people in algebraic geometry avoid using "Euler characteristic".

Answer (score 4):

The 4D physics emerging from the Calabi-Yau compactification is at the
GUT scale. In the case of a non-simply connected fundamental group,
holonomies around the loops become dynamical and can account for the
gauge symmetry breaking from the intermediate GUT level to the standard
model level. Only the generators commuting with the holonomy element
reside in the lower scale. See for example the following
[article](http://dspace.mic.ul.ie/bitstream/10395/1924/2/Andreas,%20B.%20&%20Hoffmann,%20N.%20%282012%29,%20%27SU%285%29%20heterotic%20Standard%20Model%20bundles%27%28Pre-Published%20Version%29%28Journal%20Article%29.pdf)  by Andreas and  Hoffmann, where this mechanism is
used in an $SU(5)$ GUT case.

This mechanism is known as the [Hosotani mechanism](http://inspirehep.net/record/263634?ln=en), or symmetry breaking by Wilson lines.